# Cordova FileTransfer.download fails with code 3

Tags: cordova, download, error-code

I have to download large file ( about 85MB ) using FileTransfer.download. it works fine on fast conneciton, but on slow one it fails with error code 3, http_status 200 and message "unexpected end of stream". I found similar issues with upload method after some googling. Suggested solution was to add headers. So my current code is

```
ft.download(url, fileURL, successCallback, failCallback, false, {
            headers: {
                'Connection': 'close'
            },
            'chunkedMode': 'false'
        });
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Please, could anybody help me with the issue?